# Cannot Install flutter_mapbox_navigation-0.0.26

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am trying to install: flutter_mapbox_navigation-0.0.26 to get turn by turn directions, but I keep getting this Failure:

```
[ +294 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * Where:
[        ] Build file '/Users/hsi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_mapbox_navigation-0.0.26/android/build.gradle' line: 31
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_mapbox_navigation'.
[        ] > Basedir /Users/hsi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-7.7.1/android does not exist
```

I have removed geolocator and got the same error for path provider. I also followed these steps:

[Flutter : can't build android in debug or release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919355/flutter-cant-build-android-in-debug-or-release)

But still no luck.